# MediaPlayer restarts after screen is locked

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a MediaPlayer playing Video and everything works fine except for when you lock the screen and then unlock it, the Video will restart.

Currently I'm using

```
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    lock.disableKeyguard();
```

And it works but if the you press the Home button you will not be able to lock the screen because the application has turned it off. Do you know a better approach to keep the progress of a video without having to use the KeyGuardLock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of KeyGuard you can just simply use `android:keepScreenOn=true` on your `VideoView` in the layout xml.

For the latter part, you have to save the video's progress in `onSaveInstanceState()` and load the progress data in `onRestoreInstanceState()`, than you can just use `seekTo(progress)` on your video with the data you just got back.

Also don't forget to check for null in `onRestoreInstanceState()` in case it is a new playback.

Comment: This seems like the correct approach. However, I'm not completely satisfied since I play videostreams and this will force me to rebuff the video.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you initiating your media player to play the video (mvideo.start).Is it in onCreate method or onRestart method?. It will be help full if you update your question with code to resolve this.